# Odoo 9: How to have a field displayed in edit form but not in the standard view?

Tags: xml, module, odoo, odoo-9

I have created a module which defines some fields and displays them via a view `.xml` file. How can I make it so that two of these fields (which are simply used for computing a value in another field) are only displayed when editing a record, but not when displaying it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use css class `oe_edit_only`.

```
<field name="editable_field_name" class="oe_edit_only"/>
```

This class ensures that the field is displayed only when in editable form.